# jquery1.7.2 click event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to bind a click event to some `div` that has a `id="unit"`. Theses `div` are generate in run-time and my javascript doesn't seems to work.

my javascript click event.

```
$("#unit").click(function(){
  alert('1');
});
```

before ajax call.

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="building">

    </div>

    <div id="units">

    </div>
</div>
```

after ajax call.

```
<div id="content">
        <div id="building">
            <div value="1" class="buildingBlock"><h3 style="text-align: center;">Level - 1</h3></div>
            <div value="2" class="buildingBlock"><h3 style="text-align: center;">Level - 2</h3></div>
            <div value="3" class="buildingBlock"><h3 style="text-align: center;">Level - 3</h3></div>
            <div value="4" class="buildingBlock"><h3 style="text-align: center;">Level - 4</h3></div>
        </div>


        <div id="units">
            <div value="1" id="unit">#02-01<br>3 room(s)</div>
            <div value="2" id="unit">#02-02<br>2 room(s)</div>
            <div value="3" id="unit">#02-03<br>5 room(s)</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. ID's should be unique, while `div` elements do not have `value` attribute.

Comment: This question comes up every day. Please read [Getting started with jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery) properly and read through the [API](http://api.jquery.com/).

Comment: @VisioN thanks for pointing that out. And i'm well aware of it. but having the value tag doesn't seem to affect anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are dynamically appending the `#unit` elements, you need to delegate the event to the nearest parent element. Try this:

```
$("#units").on('click', '.unit', function(){
    alert('1');
});
```

Also, multiple `id` attrbutes are invalid. You should change the code to use classes, like this:

```
<div id="units">
    <div value="1" class="unit">#02-01<br>3 room(s)</div>
    <div value="2" class="unit">#02-02<br>2 room(s)</div>
    <div value="3" class="unit">#02-03<br>5 room(s)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you cannot have more than one element with same id.

use class instead. e.g. `class="unit"`

and when you bind on event use `$(".unit")..`

---

Also, if we are considering Ajax requests, either in the success method, or in the backend you should prepare extra js code to properly init the new elements. Having event listening on parent is a hack actually.

so, if you have:

```
$.get("someurl", {}, function(data){
    $("#units").append(data);
    $("#units .unit").unbind("click").bind("click", function(){ 
// your click handler here
    });
});
```

at least I would go that way unless you have specific need to control event from parent.

Answer (score 0):

Change `id` to `class` of  `unit`

```
<div id="units">
   <div value="1" class="unit">#02-01<br>3 room(s)</div>
   <div value="2" class="unit">#02-02<br>2 room(s)</div>
   <div value="3" class="unit">#02-03<br>5 room(s)</div>
 </div>
```

Try with delegate event handler.

```
$("#units").on('click', '.unit', function(){
  alert('1');
});
```

Comment: confusing, that jquery documentation says that "Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on(). ".. but later expands that it would still cover new elements